# Nest each html element into different html blocks

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a large generated form that looks like this, with `label` tag out side the `UL LI` tags

```
<label for="title">Title:</label>
<ul class="formItem">
  <li>
   <input type="text" value="">
  </li>
</ul>

<label for="title">First Name:</label>
<ul class="formItem">
  <li>
   <input type="text" value="">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Want to nest `label` tag inside the `UL LI` using jQuery and make the form look like this

```
<ul class="formItem">
  <li>
   <label for="title">Title:</label>
   <input type="text" value="">
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="formItem">
  <li>
   <label for="title">First Name:</label>
   <input type="text" value="">
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried this, but this gets every `Label` tag on the form and sticks in the first `li`, I need each Label nested in the `li` directly after it

```
(function($) {
 jQuery(".formItem li").append(jQuery("#my-form label"));
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul.formItem').each(function () {
    $(this).find('li').prepend($(this).prev('label'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/96V4e/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use an `each` loop:

```
$('#my-form label').each(function(index) {
    $('.formItem li').eq(index).prepend(this);
});
```